# What are all the possible languages to create a mobile phone application?

Tags: programming-languages

I know j2me , Android for creating mobile phone applications. What are the other languages ?

Comment: I don't know all of them, but iOS applications use Objective-C and Symbian applications use C++.

Comment: J2ME is not a language. Android is not a language. Your argument is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just about anything. There's frameworks and SDKs for Javascript (Phonegap, NimbleKit, Unity 3D), Flash, Lua, C/C++, and Objective-C (of course). There's many more projects to bring other languages to mobile platforms.

Comment: Also Java, Python, Perl, Ruby, BeanShell, Tcl (supported via Android's SL4A) :)

Comment: I figured he knew the Java part :)